# How to extract, compare, and transform data from complicated strings using Python?

Tags: python, regex, escaping

I have a series of Maya MEL commands that I'm trying to read in, compare, and transform with Python. I am able to read in the lines, but I am having trouble extracting the data I need. Each command line contains an identifier and a series of ordered variables, usually only 3 but always symmetric with the number of variables of another line for the same identifier.

For example, I may have files that have the following:

```
// Default Lip Positions - 15_0504
setAttr("Lower_Lips.translate", 1.670481893, 10.29264716, 0.0005245589302)  ;
setAttr("Lower_Lips.rotate", 80.13419306, -90, 0);
setAttr("Lower_Lips.scale", 1, 1, 1) ;
setAttr("Lower_Lips.cv[12]", -0.5607159408, -0.815908366, 10.34516376) ;
setAttr("Lower_Lips.cv[11]", -0.5142785558, -0.9430959629, 10.29982363) ;   
// Default 15_0726
setAttr("Lower_Lips.translate", 1.670481893, 10.29264716, 0.0005245589302);
setAttr("Lower_Lips.rotate", 80.13419306, -90, 0) ;
setAttr("Lower_Lips.cv[11]", -0.4987127378, -0.9397891962, 10.31868927);
setAttr("Lower_Lips.scale", 1, 1, 1) ;
setAttr("Lower_Lips.cv[12]", -0.5437445653, -0.815908366, 10.36395894) ;
```

And I would need to extract the identifier (text between the double quotes) and associated values into a data structure. I would also need to ignore comments or empty lines. So, the first tuple would be something like:

```
('Lower_Lips.translate', '1.670481893','10.29264716','0.0005245589302')
```

And a later, more complicated command line's tuple would be:

```
('Lower_Lips.cv[12]', '-0.5607159408', '-0.815908366', '10.34516376')
```

I would then be able to look for duplicate identifiers and perform some operation on their two sets of values, like finding the difference. I was trying to do it with Regex and got as far as figuring out the identifier's pattern would be something like:

```
re.compile('.*"([^"]*)".*')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try reading in the whole file with `f.read()` and then applying this regex code on the contents:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^setAttr\("([^"]*)",\s+(\S*),\s+(\S*),\s+(\S*)\)\s*;', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "// Default Lip Positions - 15_0504\nsetAttr(\"Lower_Lips.translate\", 1.670481893, 10.29264716, 0.0005245589302)  ;\nsetAttr(\"Lower_Lips.rotate\", 80.13419306, -90, 0);\nsetAttr(\"Lower_Lips.scale\", 1, 1, 1) ;\nsetAttr(\"Lower_Lips.cv[12]\", -0.5607159408, -0.815908366, 10.34516376) ;\nsetAttr(\"Lower_Lips.cv[11]\", -0.5142785558, -0.9430959629, 10.29982363) ;   \n// Default 15_0726\nsetAttr(\"Lower_Lips.translate\", 1.670481893, 10.29264716, 0.0005245589302);\nsetAttr(\"Lower_Lips.rotate\", 80.13419306, -90, 0) ;\nsetAttr(\"Lower_Lips.cv[11]\", -0.4987127378, -0.9397891962, 10.31868927);\nsetAttr(\"Lower_Lips.scale\", 1, 1, 1) ;\nsetAttr(\"Lower_Lips.cv[12]\", -0.5437445653, -0.815908366, 10.36395894) ;"
print(re.findall(p, test_str))
```

The regex

```
^setAttr\("([^"]*)",\s+(\S*),\s+(\S*),\s+(\S*)\)\s*;
```

will just check each line and will extract necessary data from each one that conforms to the pattern.

Comment: That works very well, a lot easier that doing it line by line, too. But, I'm still having trouble getting it into a workable datastructure. Your statement prints out what looks like a list of tuples, but when I try to do something like iterate over it and get out the tuples to print individually, I get an error like: TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Pattern' object is not iterable. I'm not sure how to go from regex results to workable data.

Comment: You can use a `re.finditer` method, you might find it handier.